# Creating JSON which contains arrays and setting Key values

Tags: php, arrays, json

The Json my php is outputting contains 3 arrays, eventsIDs, TipsTB & TipsTW
when I pass the json to my html file it shows the array values with keys of 0 and 1. How do I set the Keys to be something unique like tip1 and tip2?

I create the array then endode it to JSON as below

```
function createJson($eventIds, $TipsTB, $TipsTW, $status) {

              $jsonData = new stdClass();

              $jsonData->source = "Betting Tips";
              $jsonData->published = date('Y-m-d H:s:i;');
              $jsonData->status = $status;
              $jsonData->eventIDs = $eventIds;
              $jsonData->TipsTB = $TipsTB;
              $jsonData->TipsTW = $TipsTW;

              return $jsonData;
    }

              echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

which creates

```
Object {source: "Betting Tips", published: "2015-05-21 12:54:56;", status: true, eventIDs: Array[2], TipsTB: Array[2], TipsTW: Array[0]}
```

How do I make the keys of the 3 arrays other than 0,1,2,3...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `$jsonData` an array rather than `stdClass`. Than assign your data to the keys of that array. It should work

```
$jsonData = array();

$jsonData['foo'] = $TipsTB;
$jsonData['bar'] = 42;

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that is exacly what I'm after because it still does not put the keys inside the $TipsTB BUT if I do that in the function that creates the $TipsTB array then that should work no? $TipsTB['Tip1'] = $TipsTB[0] I'm going to try that now... Thanks!